# array overwrites other previously inserted data

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to insert values to an  empty array during every iteration, the code that i have now inserts the value at the index but overwrites all the previous values, Im not sure what to do about this,

```
#Empty array is created here 
complete = np.empty((128, 86), dtype = float)

#From the result dictionary elements are appended here 
feature_1 = np.array([])
feature_2 = np.array([])
try:
    for key, value in six.iteritems(result_1):
        if key.startswith("original_"):
            feature_1 = np.append( feature_1, result_1[key])
            feature_2 = np.append( feature_2, result_2[key])

    #And here i try to insert the feature_1 array to this array
    complete[index, :] = feature_1
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful.
Do let me know if you need more clarification , code etc
thanks in advance.

**Example** 
during iteration 1 the array `complete` has all random values except the `first` index, due to this operation `complete[index, :] = feature_1` now during the second operation the `first` index values goes to random values but the `second` element has the feature value and this repeats for all values when in the end all the values will have random values except the `last` index

**Fixed it**. The mistake was that i was reinitializing the empty array during every iteration ,Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "*he code that i have now inserts the value at the index but overwrites all the previous values,*"? Can you add a minimal and verifiable example to your question and show us what's the problem. Besides, you're not assigning items to the empty array at each iteration `complete[index, :] = feature_1` is out of the `for` loop.

Comment: He means, _"the code I have now inserts a value at an index but also overwrites all the data previous to that index"_ Top of the morning to you to mate :)

Comment: wait i think Ive made a stupid mistake ,during every loop it initializes the `complete` array i think thats the reason it overwrites,let me cross check